# Find string and replace with line breaks and indentions

Tags: xml, linux, bash, shell, replace

I'd like to find a specific string in a file and replace it like following:

In the file test*.xml

```
<root>
    <list>
        <item ID="abc">
            <amount>1</amount>
            <text>TEST</text>
        </item>
        <item ID="cde">
            <amount>1</amount>
            <text>TEST 2</text>
        </item>
    </list>
</root>
```

replace this with

```
<root>
    <list>
        <item ID="abc">
            <amount>0</amount>
            <text>TEST</text>
        </item>
        <item ID="cde">
            <amount>1</amount>
            <text>TEST 2</text>
        </item>
    </list>
</root>
```

So far I have this:

```
find . -name "test*" -print | xargs sed -i 's/<item ID=\"abc\">/<item ID=\"abc\">/g'
```

Well, it does of course nothing, but I don't know how I'm able to "skip" the line break and the spaces. I'm not allowed to alter the indentions.
I tried to do it with a one-liner but a small bash script should do the trick too, but I'm very inexperienced with bash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would rather use an XML-aware tool to manipulate XML, such that you can maintain well-formedness, character/entity encodings etc.

[XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) works well. It will allow you to use XPath to specify particular nodes in the XML and change these. I don't think you should really have to worry about indentation etc. That's normally just regarded as formatting.

Comment: yea, you may be right. I just thought I could make it quick and dirty.

Comment: Sometimes quick-and-dirty is fine. Sometimes, however, it's not!